# Shutdown computer using powershell with a popup window to be able to abort

Tags: powershell, timer, popup, shutdown

I have been trying for a while to send out a script that restarts the computers on my place of work. I want the user of the computer to be able to say no to the restart if the person is currently working on the computer. Therefore I have a set time before the computer will shutdown. The user recieves a pop-up window in which they can abort the restart and continue their work.

My initial try with shutdown worked but the reason for the restarts are, ofcourse, to run updates which doesnt happen using shutdown as I understand it.

My co-worker has made a script in c++ which can execute the shutdown and update all files, so we want to incorporate this with my code. Can someone help me figure out how to do this?

Summary: 
The user must have a time to be able to abort the restart
A pop-up window that the user can use to do this and see that it is happening
The shutdown must be able to update the computer also.

Pardon the Swedish if there is any trouble. Avbryt menas abort, starta om means restart

Thank you

> 

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 

shutdown -r -t 1200
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Cambria",10,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Italic)
#Placering

$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$objForm.Font =$Font
$objForm.Text = "Datorn startas om"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$objForm.MinimizeBox = $False
$objForm.MaximizeBox = $False
$objForm.WindowState = "Normal"
$objForm.SizeGripStyle = "Hide"
$objForm.ShowInTaskbar = $False

#Enter och Esc kan användas

$objForm.KeyPreview = $True
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
    {$objForm.close()}})
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
    {$objForm.Close(); shutdown -a}})

    #En av knapparna

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,120)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,23)
$OKButton.Text = "Starta om"
$OKButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close();shutdown -a; shutdown -r -f})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)

#Den andra knappen

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,120)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Avbryt"
$CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close(); shutdown -a})
$objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

#En text och dess placering och storlek

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,100) 
$objLabel.Text = "En schemalagd omstart är påväg att starta. För att förhindra detta klicka på Avbryt.
klicka på Starta om för att starta om datorn nu. Annars kommer omstarten att ske om 20 minuter. "
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel)


$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: I'd say use `shutdown -t timeout` to signify the logged-on user(s) that there's a shutdown in progress, therefore a user with enough privileges can run `shutdown -a` themselves, saving you work.

Comment: did you  know the built-in shutdown.exe can do this ?

Comment: @Vesper `-i` to add a gui

Comment: @Kayasax That GUI only displays the execution parameters while not initiating the shutdown, OP means to initiate the shutdown and allow the *remote user* to cancel the shutdown.

Comment: @Vesper really? I think I've used it before to display alert.... But maybe was on the localhosr

Comment: @Kayasax Yes, if you just do `shutdown -r -t 300` you'll see an alert saying "Shutdown in progress", and if you do `shutdown -a` while the time is not up, the window disappears, if it wasn't closed manually. Just tried that on the localhost, though, I don't want to experiment on live systems, but IIRC RDP users get notified as well if a shutdown is in progress.

Comment: @Vesper yes that's it I  was in rdv session

Comment: @vesper Yes ofcourse you can use shutdown -a but the people on my workspace aren't IT people and can not do that sort of thing. Therefore my code must use a window as above so they can use it.

Comment: @Phil Usually when an admin orders restart, a user obeys. 20 minutes is probably enough to save one's work and go for a dinner.

Comment: @Vesper Well this will be run on a daily basis so, yes I want to give them the option.

Comment: I would use "Stop-Computer" instead of "shutdown" command of cmd to keep it in powershell style.